# .htaccess: How do I block referers EXCEPT for specific dirs?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I want to block all accesses to a website from domain1 and domain2 unless they specifically go to `/` and `/media`. So far I have:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} domain1\.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} domain2\.com [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

This works perfectly except that it blocks *all* requests. I want to allow incoming links from these two domains to be able to access `/` and `/media` *only*. So far I haven't been able to figure it out.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sorry for the earlier answer; I've updated it with a (hopefully,) more complete possible answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} domain1\.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} domain2\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !media [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*)$ $1 [R,L]
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

Checked the syntax on: http://www.lyxx.com/freestuff/002.html

Comment: Your first code is correct Summea. Apache removes the leading slash in RewriteRule.

Comment: It does work however for the dirs that it doesn't block, Apache serves the default virtual host instead of the correct one! That's a completely different problem so I'm going to mark the answer as accepted. Thanks summea!

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} (:/|\.)(domain1|domain2)\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*$|media/)       -                      [skip=1] 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} (:/|\.)(domain1|domain2)\.com [NC]
RewriteRule .*                     -                      [F]
```

No external redirections are needed.  I am assuming here that you'll also allow `*.domain1.com` etc.